# Deploying a Laravel Project in Web Host

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I've followed different guides in uploading my Laravel project in [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/#gref), but unfortunately there is always an error, it won't load the index.php.

Here is the structure in my file manager.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIixz.jpg

This is my **public** files in the **public_html**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSQvN.jpg

This is the code inside **index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../sample/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../sample/bootstrap/app.php';
```

When I try to open the site.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmh9O.jpg

Did I miss something?

Comment: It gives you 500 error, you should be able to check in webserver logs what the issue is exactly.

Comment: Are you running [tag:apache] or [tag:nginx] and how is it configured ?

Comment: Please, share your error log.

Comment: Why did you move the `public` folder outside the laravel root dir? Was this a specific  requirement?

Comment: Ahhh.. Good old Internal Server Error(500). My guess is that the problem is specifically here `__DIR__.'/../sample/vendor/autoload.php';`. I sense the path evaluates to something that you do not expect. In worst case it's an invalid path. But it doesn't really relate to every other comment though

Comment: I can't find my error log file, there's no error log file in storage/logs.

Comment: When I put index.html/php file it works. But when I upload my laravel project, it comes up with Server Error 500

Comment: @Tonzkie Probably because your web server on production is configured differently. Check the config and logs, probably in `/var/log` somewhere.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin what's the best way to fix that? I already tried `__DIR__.'/../../sample/vendor/autoload.php';` and `__DIR__.'/sample/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @Tonzkie, That is a good question - you could try to drop `_DIR_` and use something along the lines of plain `/sample/vendor/autoload.php` . [Php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is not very clear on how `_DIR_` works, but it explains it a bit. You could also do check `var_dump(_DIR_)` to see what value it contains and do a `var_dump(__DIR__.'/../sample/vendor/autoload.php')`, the last one should be very interesting.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin here is the result when I try to **print_r** the two. `/home/u928171126/domains/parking-ally.com/public_html/vendor/autoload.php`
`/home/u928171126/domains/parking-ally.com/public_html/bootstrap/app.php`

this is what I did, and I think it is in the right path already, but still internal server error 500.

`print_r(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'.'<br/>'.__DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php');`

Answer (score 0):

For some more clarification on the issue, I decided to post an answer.

The main problem that provided code has is

```
require __DIR__.'/../sample/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../sample/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Both paths are probably invalid. Judging by earlier comments, the foders don't exist.

According to [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `_DIR_` will hold the directory of a current file - actually more correct would be sayin it holds a directory of a file in which it resides.

`_DIR_` variable is hard to work with, when it comes to creating absolute paths, because it already is almost an absolute path of a current file.

There are several other ways to get the correct path, and among them the most basic, probably easiest and probably fastest would be using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, which holds

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file. [From Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

I will try to provide some exaples which show the issues with `_DIR_` variable and how `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` can be used.

I will also be somewhat replicating your structure at a very basic level.

***NOTE: All my examples are running on a localhost under Windows, which only further will prove that `_DIR_` is un-reliable***

I took your file structire and simlified it to just two folders, one file in each folder. My relative file structure looks literally like:

`public_html/index.php` and `sample/include.php`.

Now inside *index.php* first you put this code

```
<?php

echo __DIR__.'/../sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

Which will output `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWordpress\public_html/../sample/include.php` when I run it. The output is a valid path on Windows though and doing `require` on it should work.

Now I am changing *index.php* to

```
<?php

echo __DIR__.'/sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

*NOTE:* i basically only removed `/../` from the path.

When i run it again - the output will be `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWordpress\public_html/sample/include.php` which will be a very invalid path on Windows. - folder does not exist.

The two examples above proove that `_DIR_` variable is un-reliable.

Now consider the following *index.php*

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

When I run this - it will output `For some more clarification on the issue, I decided to post an answer.

The main problem that provided code has is

```
require __DIR__.'/../sample/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../sample/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Both paths are probably invalid paths, since both probably do not exist.

According to [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `_DIR_` will hold the directory of a current file - actually more correct would be sayin it holds a directory of a file in which it resides.

`_DIR_` variable is hard to work with, when it comes to creating absolute paths, because it already is almost an absolute path.

There are several other ways to get the correct path, and among them the most basic, probably easiest and probably fastest would be using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, which holds

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file. [From Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

I will try to provide some exaples which show the issues with `_DIR_` variable and how `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` can be used.

I will also be somewhat replicating your structure at a very basic level.

***NOTE: All my examples are running on a localhost under Windows***

I took your file structire and simlified it to just two folders, one file in each folder. My relative file structure looks literally like:

`public_html/index.php` and `sample/include.php`.

Now inside *index.php* first you put this code

```
<?php

echo __DIR__.'/../sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

Which will output `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWordpress\public_html/../sample/include.php` when I run it. The output however is valid path on Windows and doing `require` on it should work.

Now I am changing *index.php* to

```
<?php

echo __DIR__.'/sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

*NOTE:* i basicallyc only removed `/../` from the path.

When i run it again - the output will be `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWordpress\public_html/sample/include.php` which is a very invalid path on Windows. The folder does not exist.

Now consider the following **index.php**

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/include.php<br>';

?>
```

When I run this - it will output `C:/xampp/htdocs/myWordpress/sample/include.php` which is an *Existing, Valid Path*, that can be later used in require for example.

A working example that shows the usage and the output differense between `_DIR_` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will probabply look like below

**index.php**

```
<?php

echo 'Directory of index.php file is:<span style="color:red">'. __DIR__.'</span></br>';
echo 'File include.php will be included from:<span style="color:red">'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/include.php</span></br>' ;
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/sample/include.php";

?>
```

**include.php**

```
<?php

echo 'Directory of include.php file determined by `__DIR__` is:<span style="color:red">'. __DIR__.'</span></br>';
echo 'Directory of include.php file determined by usage of $_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\']:<span style="color:red">'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/include.php</span></br>';

?>
```

I made the paths red, to bring extra attention to them.

This example will show that `__DIR__` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` return different results, on the same system, on the same virtual server.

**DIR** can also be used to achive the same result with pure Windows paths - it will be ugly though.

Adding line

```
echo 'The valid directory of include.php file using __DIR__ is:<span style="color:red">'.__DIR__.'\\..\\sample\\</span></br>';
```

to **index.php** will somewhat show that **DIR** can be used on **Windows, and Windows only!**, on Unix this should and would fail. It also shows that it's usage is somewhat platform specific, which also means not very reliable.

**EDIT**
The example above is actually very bad. It shows wrong and ugly coding. And I would not have shown it, if I have't seen an actual production code like this once. (Not mine)

The bottom line for all these examples is - Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in creating paths and do not use `__DIR__`.

I hope my examples somewhat show why i think `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a better idea.

**Edit 1** I guess my links to doc's and explanation were not that good.

Judging by the images of your file structure your paths should be:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sample/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But that really depends on what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains. And what the relative paths to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contain.

Comment: I've tried changing the `__DIR__` to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but viola, still internal error, this is really getting frustrating now since I really need to up this project.

https://imgur.com/a/AEl14i8

Comment: @Tonzkie, The paths in the image are again incorrect. You should really check if the resulting paths exist. Your only problem right now is that you  can't correctly make a path to your require files. Require only fails for very few reasons - one of them is providing it with wrong path. I strongly suggest reading up on the workings of `$_SERVER` variables and other Php constants. It will help in the future

Comment: I've tried uploading it via git repository, and now it loads the bootstrap, but still I have this 500 error. I think it still don't load the autoload.